# convert tree-manager npm module (filetree) for koajs / co compatibility

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, yield, koa

How do I get a list of files compatible with co/yield (for koajs) ?

I am trying to convert this module for koa/co: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-manager

The original function is

```
fileModule.prototype.walkDir = function(dir, done) {
var self = this;
var results = [];
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
if (err) {
  return done(err);
}
console.log(pending)
var pending = list.length;
if(!pending) {
  return done(null, results);
}
list.forEach(function(file) {
  var dfile = path.join(dir, file);
  var el = {};
  var fid = path.join(dir.replace(self.root, ''), file);
  el.text = file;
  el.id = fid;
  fs.stat(dfile, function(err, stat) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    if(stat.isDirectory()) {
      return self.walkDir(dfile, function(err, res) {
        el.children = res;
        results.push(el);
        !--pending && done(null, results);
      });
    }
    el.icon = 'file'; // @TODO - to settings
    el.a_attr = {id: fid};
    results.push(el);
    !--pending && done(null, results);
    });
   });
  });
}
```

I can replace `require('fs')` with `co-fs-plus` (or extra)

so i can remove all fs callbacks with simple yield fs.xxx

but i don t understand the `foreach` loop :/

### UPDATE (solution):

so ...

add wrap to co and adding dfile to the isDirectory function seems working

```
  fileModule.prototype.walkDir = co.wrap(function*(dir) {
  var self = this;
  var list = yield fs.readdirAsync(dir);
  // yield a list of promises
  // created by mapping with an asynchronous function
  var results = yield list.map(co.wrap(function*(file) {
    var dfile = path.join(dir, file);
    var fid = path.join(dir.replace(self.root, ''), file);
    var el = {
      text: file,
      id: fid
    };
    try {
      if (yield fs.isDirectoryAsync(dfile)) {
        el.children = yield self.walkDir(dfile);
      } else {
        el.icon = 'file'; // @TODO - to settings
        el.a_attr = {id: fid};
      }
      return el;
    } catch(err) {
      el.icon = 'file'; // @TODO - to settings
      el.a_attr = {id: fid+' !! FILE UNREADABLE !!'};
      return el;
    }
  }));
  return results;
})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

That loops runs all the actions in parallel, that's why it's so complicated (with the `pending` thingy and all). However, doing things in parallel is not really a strength of `co`, you should look into *promises* for that.

```
import fs from 'fs-extra-promise';

fileModule.prototype.walkDir = co(function*(dir) {
  var self = this;
  var list = yield fs.readdirAsync(dir);
// yield a list of promises
// created by mapping with an asynchronous function
  var results = yield list.map(co(function*(file) {
    var dfile = path.join(dir, file);
    var fid = path.join(dir.replace(self.root, ''), file);
    var el = {
      text: file,
      id: fid
    };
    if (yield fs.isDirectoryAsync()) {
      el.children = yield self.walkDir(dfile);
    } else {
      el.icon = 'file'; // @TODO - to settings
      el.a_attr = {id: fid};
    }
    return el;
  }));
  return results;
});
```

Comment: import fs from 'fs-extra-promise'? What syntax is this?

Comment: @user619271: it's ES6, just like generators are. I thought you'd use it, as you tagged your question with it :-) It's not supported in node yet, though, so if you don't use a transpiler then just make usual `require(…)` call.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Never heard about this before. Question is not mine though.